# Django inspectdb take account of camel casing

Tags: python, django, naming-conventions

I have models that I am keeping track of with nodeJS knex.

in the migration, I am using Camel casing for both table names and the column names.

I expected the django inspectdb to take account of camelcasing and produce snake case result as the class fields; however, column `logoImgName` ends up translating to `logoimgname` where I would like it to be `logo_img_name`.

Is it possible to let django know that the column names are in camel casing and it should be converted to snake case when running inspectdb?

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    logoimgname = models.CharField(db_column='logoImgName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    createdat = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt')  # Field name made lowercase.
    updatedat = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'company'
```

Comment: `inspectdb` is not meant to be a solution to auto generating models from existing tables, it's a helper to get started integrating the ORM with a legacy DB. As such, it doesn't have a particularly rich API and you can't do what you want unless you create your own `inspectdb` that does

Comment: This is the line you would want to look at when extending the current command https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py#L110